# Sphinx built file in project

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am packaging my first project with Sphinx for PYPI. I created documentation with Sphinx, in the `docs/source` folder. My question is: is it customary to provide the built documentation as well in the repo? How is it usually done?

I'm asking because I can imagine lots of people won't have installed or even heard of Sphinx. I would like to make their life easy as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is not software.

I do not know of any packages on PyPI that include documentation, except for its `README.rst` and release notes.  There might be some that include docs.

If packages have documentation, it is common to put a `docs` folder as a sibling to the package's source folder in the repository.  Then when releasing to PyPI, only the source folder is uploaded.

Now that does not mean you can not include documentation with your PyPI release, but there are some negatives to go with that, including unnecessary download times and inability of users to find the documentation on their file system after installing your package.  There are alternatives.  [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/) is a popular service that can be configured to build documentation on every change to your repository, and to make it available in HTML (either online or downloadable .zip), PDF, or ePub formats.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I am placing the `docs` in a sibling to the package's source folder, as you suggest. But in the `MANIFEST.in` I am including `docs/source/*` where the Sphinx source files are. You mean I should not?

Comment: Nope. `docs` is where you keep your `.rst` files. `src` or `mypackage` is where you keep your package's source code. See [Pyramid repo](https://github.com/pylons/pyramid) for a common pattern. You can also find other useful information about how we build docs in HACKING.txt in that repo.